# RLE-архив. Как понять, что файл повреждён?

Tags: архивация, rle

Даны два файла, один из них сжат с помощью алгоритма [RLE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%EE%E4%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5_%E4%EB%E8%ED_%F1%E5%F0%E8%E9)

Как программе по содержимому файлов распознать, являются они RLE-архивами или нет?

Comment: попытаться распаковать и посмотреть, что выйдет? Но в общем случае - никак. Поэтому обычно к таким файлам добавляют заголовки.

Comment: Моя мысль была немного другой. Добавить к концу каждой последовательности пустой бит. В таком случае, если последовательность заканчивается не пустым битом - файл поврежден или не является архивом.

Но можно ли как-то обойтись без модификаций алгоритма?

Comment: @Inkognito, RLE сам по себе не имеет средств контроля целостности. Самый простой вариант - в начало добавлять значение контрольной суммы, даже алгоритм не придется изменять.

Answer (score 1):

В RLE нет встроенных средств проверки и/или контроля целостности и правильности. Любая последовательность байт может быть "скормлена" алгоритму распаковки.

Для правильного распознавания, обычно, добавляет заголовок, чтобы было точно ясно, что это RLE архив. Также добавляют размер/контрольную сумму содержимого, чтобы после распаковки можно было их сверить, и сказать корректно ли прошла распаковка.